# How to create app non layout?

Tags: android, layout

I want to create an app non layout. When the user touches the icon then do something and not show layout.
How to do this?

I try `finish();`

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //do something
    finish();
}
```

but it not perfect, it show layout delay.
I want nothing show. Please help me if you know that.

Thanks for read!

Comment: Have you tried setting android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" in Manifest to Activity

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);if you need no layout , you should don't setContentview and use a theme has no Actionbar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put android:theme attribute of application in manifest as following.

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"** >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

And do not set the in your activity.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```